# Drawing bridges with some elements like cars and bicycles

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Just for fun. Is it possible to draw the following with tikz (including a small car and a bicycle)?

[image]

[image]

Here's an attempt by me to implement it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth,center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
    minor tick num=1,
    %grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={=>},
    xlabel={\small $x$},,
    ylabel={\small $f(x)$},
    ylabel style={xshift=0cm, yshift=0.22cm},
    x=0.25cm,
    y=0.25cm,
    ytick={-40,-38,...,40},
    xtick={-30,-28,...,30},
    %xticklabels = {, , , -2, ,2 , ,,},
    %yticklabels = {, ,-2 ,, 2, , ,,},
    ymin=-40.33,
    ymax=40.33,
    xmin=-40.33,
    xmax=40.33,
]
\addplot [color=red, domain=-20:20, samples=100, thick] {0.03125*x^2};
\addplot [color=red, domain=-40:-20, samples=100, thick] {0.03125*(x+40)^2};
\addplot [color=red, domain=20:40, samples=100, thick] {0.03125*(x-40)^2};
\addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(15, 0) (15,225/32)};
\addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(10, 0) (10,25/8)};
\addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(5, 0) (5,25/32)};
\addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(-15, 0) (-15,225/32)};
\addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(-10, 0) (-10,25/8)};
\addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(-5, 0) (-5,25/32)};
\addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(20,-10) (20,20)};
\addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(-20,-10) (-20,20)};
\addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(-20,12.5) (20,12.5)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A first approach, with `fontawesome5` (Is this cheating?):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\tikzset{vehicle/.style={anchor=base,scale=0.5,teal}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \node[vehicle] at (1,\pgflinewidth) {\faBiking};
  \node[vehicle] at (5,\pgflinewidth) {\faCarSide};
  \node[vehicle] at (4,\pgflinewidth) {\faAmbulance};
  \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (6,0);
  \foreach\i in {1.5,4.5}
  {
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\i,0)}]
      \draw[thick] (0,-1) -- (0,3);
      \foreach\j in {-1,1}
      {
        \draw[blue] (1.5*\j,0) parabola (0,2);
        \foreach\k in {1,2,3}
          \draw[blue!60] (1.5*\j-0.375*\j*\k,0) --++ (0,0.125*\k*\k);
      }
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Haha...I didn't even know these symbols existed :D
Really cool!

Comment: Not cheating. It is so you do not have to re-invent the wheel :)